# Contacts not shown in contacts app - when using sample contact manager application

Tags: android, contacts, android-2.2-froyo

When using the sample app - contact manager, and adding a contact where you have not set up an account. The contacts get written to the database, but do not show up in the contacts application. The contacts application also does not seem to require an account be setup, but does show contacts which are added through the menu -> add method.

Is there an updated ContactManager app for 2.2+ which addresses this issue? Is there a missing parameter that needs to be set to allow visibility on the android contacts application?

The only difference seems to be that the contact_in_visible_group is set to zero when it is added via the ContactManager, it is set to one when set via the contacts application. Looking through the android source code for Contacts did not seem to yield any way to modify this value, and no way to change it via the API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you pass a NULL account name in w/ the new contact not a blank string..